# PHP - Syntax errors no longer showing (blank white page)

Tags: php

Server got upgraded from PHP 5.2 to 5.3 and now I am no longer getting syntax errors, just a blank white page. I know this is a common question, and I normally know what needs to be done, I've just never had this situation before.

php.ini has display_errors on and error_reporting is set to E_ALL & E_NOTICE. Are there any other directives that could be affecting it? I used to get syntax error messages (`"Unexpected ; in file on line..."`).

Am I being really stupid here?

Comment: Are you reading from the correct php.ini file, and are you sure that display_errors or error_reporting is not redefined later in the file?

Comment: Maybe try putting `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of the file to see if that works?

Comment: wrt to the first comment, if you add a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` you can determine which php.ini file your site is using

Comment: Yes, I'm reading the correct php.ini and the directives are only defined once in the file.  I have tried adding error_reporting(-1) to the PHP file itself but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: It probably doesn't address your question as to why errors aren't being reported but you can run a PHP lint-check using the php executable on the file to get an actual error message: `php -l myFile.php`. This should catch syntax error, not run-time errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the directive slightly wrong.  The correct value in php.ini needs to be:

`E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`

Answer (score 1):

try in php.ini

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
display_errors = On
```

save and restart apache

Answer (score 0):

you didnt mention the OS but assuming you work on an Unix variant, you can see the errors by running this command :

```
tail -f /var/logs/apache2/error.log
```

or maybe

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

And the web server configurations might have been changed too.

Comment: Yeah but I want them to appear on the PHP page as before.